# Loading a local image with JavaScript/jQuery where I know the location, but not the file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, linux-mint

The new version of Linux Mint allows HTML 5 login window themes -- I'm trying to write one that will grab each user's wallpaper. These wallpapers are located in the folder `/home/#USER#/.cache/wallpaper/`, however the file name is not consistent and I need a programmatic way of determining it. Once I know the filename, the login screen *will* display the image correctly using the `file:///..` format.

I don't have any tools other than client-side HTML/CSS/JavaScript[/jQuery/etc] available to me. Is there any way I can grab the file names in that directory, so that I can grab the wallpaper image?

EDIT: Figured it out! The browsers won't allow access to the `file:///` resources at all, the `mdm-theme-emulator` *will*.

Comment: What application are you doing this in? It doesn't sound like you're talking about the web browser.

Comment: Tools for GUI customization might be better asked in unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The HTML 5 themes use a webkit renderer. So I've been testing in the web browser. As mentioned, my only tools are HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Looking into it some more, I've found that jQuery also cannot load the image raw, the only way is by inserting an `img` tag with the correct source. I'm thinking this isn't do-able.

Comment: If it supports CSS, you may be able to use `background-image: url(file:///...)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these files are located on the client machine, in which case you would not be able to access them using jQuery. Javascript does not have access to the local file system.

If you are sending the request through a server, you'd be able to use the server-side code (ASP.NET, PHP, etc.) to loop through the filenames

Comment: It doesn't sound like he's doing this in a browser, but in some other application used to customize the GUI. It may not have the same restrictions as a browser.